# Google disabled use of Maps API for this Application

Tags: html, google-maps

I am developing a basic site for a company and there is a map on the contact page. I put in the google API and it was working fine for a few hours. Then all of a sudden an error started to show up that says:

Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this application. The provided key is not a valid Google API Key, or it is not authorized for the Google Maps Javascript API v3 on this site. If you are the owner of this application, you can learn about obtaining a valid key here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Obtaining_Key

I would reset my API key but I have two other active sites using that key. Is there a limit to the number of sites that can use the API key? These sites are not high traffic at all so I doubt I have reached the 25,000 per day limit.

Does anyone know what the problem might be? I don't think it is in the code because it was working fine before. Why would Google disable it?

I am not a very experienced programmer so can anyone help me in simple terms?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Not sure if keys need to be unique per site, but I'd take a look at that.

Comment: No they don't need to be unique per site, if you did not enter a referer-URL when creating it.

Answer (score 0):

Hey check this out https://developers.google.com/maps/signup cant post it as link writing from cell phone. You dont need a API key if you use V3 of the API. Hope this helps you!

Edit: Im using the console key to monitor my sites requests :)